# Smudge Error: Smudge Filter LFS Failed during Git Pull

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, unreal-engine4, pull, git-lfs

I am a part of a Game Development Team. We are developing an [Unreal Engine 4](https://www.unrealengine.com/en-US/) game for PC. We have a private [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/) Server handling version control of the project.

Right now, when anyone tries to Git Pull from a specific branch of our Git Project, they receive a **Smudge Error**:

```
Downloading UE4Proj/Content/Game/Art/Architecture/MedievalVillage/Textures/Bucket_A.uasset (1.3 MB)
Error downloading object: UE4Proj/Content/Game/Art/Architecture/MedievalVillage/Textures/Bucket_A.uasset (c366451): Smudge error: Error downloading Ue4Proj/Content/Game/Art/Architecture/MedievalVillage/Textures/Bucket_A.uasset (c366451e360519497bf1719bacdc40c938c833adf9b8060d90d0829fec15d6c8): expected OID c366451e360519497bf1719bacdc40c938c833adf9b8060d90d0829fec15d6c8, got e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855 after 0 bytes written

error: external filter 'git-lfs filter-process' failed
fatal: UE4Proj/Content/Game/Art/Architecture/MedievalVillage/Textures/Bucket_A.uasset: smudge filter lfs failed
```

We had the Developer that created this branch remove `Bucket_A.uasset` and repush the change. When anyone tries to Git Pull now, they receive a **Smudge Error** with a different file:

```
Downloading UE4Proj/Content/Game/Art/Architecture/MedievalVillage/Textures/Bucket_C.uasset (1.4 MB)
Error downloading object: UE4Proj/Content/Game/Art/Architecture/MedievalVillage/Textures/Bucket_C.uasset (4023793): Smudge error: Error downloading UE4Proj/Content/Game/Art/Architecture/MedievalVillage/Textures/Bucket_C.uasset (40237933795d4ca4b4c58e2884e219c3e4cd8168af176f01b33d71e3353376d7): expected OID 40237933795d4ca4b4c58e2884e219c3e4cd8168af176f01b33d71e3353376d7, got e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855 after 0 bytes written

error: external filter 'git-lfs filter-process' failed
fatal: UE4Proj/Content/Game/Art/Architecture/MedievalVillage/Textures/Bucket_C.uasset: smudge filter lfs failed
```

So this isn't some isolated incident: it looks like there could be **Smudge Errors** for multiple files. The really aggravating part is that the Smudge Error *only* shows up at around 99% of the Git Pull, so going through and deleting the file with a **Smudge Error** (whatever it is) manually after an hour or two attempting a Git Pull, and then Repushing the change, is proving to be a huge chore and will certainly cause problems with the Unreal Engine Project itself (since Textures will now be missing).

Unreal Engine is reporting no issue for either of these UASSET files, which tells me there is nothing wrong with the content of these files.

To Git Pull the project, we have Team Member using [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) and Windows Command Line. They're all receiving this same error.

What is a **Smudge Error**, and are there any recommendations for dealing with these so we can get this Git Branch to Pull successfully? Is this an issue that needs to be resolved by individual Pullers, the Pusher and/or the Git Server Host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I resolved the issue: we ended up rolling back our GitLab VM to a time *prior* to a Git Push that had caused the GitLab VM to lock up (it took several attempts before the Git Branch was pushed at that time). After rolling back the GitLab VM, I added more RAM and CPU to the VM: the Git Branch was pushed again and this time without the GitLab VM locking up. Once successfully pushed, the branch could be pulled without error! So we no longer receive `Smudge Error`s when pulling the branch (or any other branch in the Git Project for that matter, as I'll explain further).

We believe that ever since that event of the GitLab VM locking up during a Git Push, the Project Git Repository was corrupted. Indeed, **anyone** pulling from **any** of our Project Branches (minus **master** for some reason) were receiving `Smudge Error`s, including from previous branches that were pullable without error before! I am *very* thankful that regular snapshots and backups are performed on our Git Server.

Word of warning to anyone hosting a Git Server: if a big push is about to be attempted, snapshot AND backup the Git Server first. Trust me, you REALLY don't want a corrupted Git repository!

Answer (score 1):

Git LFS uses a smudge and clean filter to turn the pointer files in the repository into the large files that you checked in.  The smudge process is this process.

The message you're seeing is because Git LFS is trying to download the object from the server and its hash is incorrect.  Git LFS uses SHA-256 to identify files and the file it's receiving is the empty file (of which `e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855` is the hash), not the file you intended.  This is a problem in your server; it's not a problem with Git or Git LFS.

If you try to upload the object again, GitLab will probably think that it already has the object and not request that it be uploaded.  You will need to tell GitLab to delete the existing object, however that is done, and then push the object again from a client that has it.

If you're seeing a large number of files with this problem, your GitLab instance may have a serious problem.  Truncated, zero-length files are a common problem when a machine crashes, and you should inspect your GitLab instance for any problems.  If you're unsure how to do that, you should contact GitLab for support.

Comment: Are you sure this is a problem with our Server, and not with the Git Push that was done? That seems to be what our Lead Programmer is thinking right now. Is there a way to delete specific files from a Branch using Git (GitLab doesn't allow LFS files to be deleted in the Web GUI) and repush them? Or does the entire branch need deleted and the entire branch needs repushed? It's a big branch.

Comment: Your server should check the size of the object that's uploaded and not accept the object if it's not the right size, even if it doesn't check the hash, so your server is broken if it doesn't do that.  The Git LFS upload protocol is designed to perform a verify operation where the server can validate the uploaded object.  It doesn't provide a way to delete objects, though.  I can't speak for what GitLab does or doesn't do; I'm not familiar with it, so you'll have to ask them.

Comment: I believe you're correct that it is indeed the server, or perhaps the entire project repository: the master branch is fine, but when anyone tries pulling from any other branch, they receive "smudge errors". I have no idea what I'd need to do to fix things. Do you have any recommended Git or Git LFS communities I could turn to? I'm quite worried I will need to turn to more then just the GitLab Community.

Comment: You can ask a question on the [Git LFS GitHub Discussions board](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/discussions).  This isn't an issue, so opening it as an issue wouldn't be the right thing to do.  I will tell you that there aren't a lot of people familiar with GitLab on the Git LFS project, so I"d definitely ask GitLab first.